# Flutter: How do I get futureBuilder to feed my custom widgets data?

Tags: flutter, dart, future, flutter-futurebuilder

I made a custom feedCard widget that accepts a heading, body, and image as parameters. My understanding of the FutureBuilder is a little lacking and after countless outdated tutorials I cant seem to get a feed running properly. I haven't setup firebase yet so I'm attempting to use a preset list of data for testing purposes which I believe is the area giving me issues.

This is my feed widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_app/theme.dart';
import 'package:my_app/widgets/feed_card_widget.dart';

class Feed extends StatefulWidget {
  Feed({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Feed> createState() => _FeedState();
}

class _FeedState extends State<Feed> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: FutureBuilder(
                  future: _getPosts(),
                  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.data == null) {
                      return const Center(
                        child: Text('Loading'),
                      );
                    } else {
                      return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return FeedCard(
                            headingText: snapshot.data[index].headingText,
                            bodyText: snapshot.data[index].bodyText,
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Post {
  final int index;
  final String headingText;
  final String bodyText;

  Post(
    this.index,
    this.headingText,
    this.bodyText,
  );
}

List<Post> postList = <Post>[
  Post(1, 'headingText', 'bodyText'),
  Post(2, 'headingText', 'bodyText'),
  Post(3, 'headingText', 'bodyText'),
  Post(4, 'headingText', 'bodyText'),
  Post(5, 'headingText', 'bodyText'),
];

//Future function
Future<List<Post>> _getPosts() async {
  var postData = postList;

  //List being returned
  List<Post> posts = [];

  for (var p in postData) {
    Post post = Post(
      p['index'],
      p['headingText'],
      p['bodyText'],
    );
    posts.add(post);
  }

  print(posts.length);

  return posts;
}
```

And the trouble line of code is:

```
    Post post = Post(
      p['index'],
      p['headingText'],
      p['bodyText'],
    );
    posts.add(post);
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking. For example, is the actual problem the list of posts that doesn't update with the new posts added?

Comment: Do *NOT* build your future in the "future:" parameter to FutureBuilder!  Read the first few paragraphs of the FutureBuilder documentation for the details, or watch my video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqE-J8YJnpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your `postData` is already has a type of List. But you're trying to convert it into List which is not necessary.

- If you want your mock data to be already in List class.
  Just test it like this:

```
import 'dart:async';

Future<List<Post>> _getPosts() async {
    return Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500))
        .then((onValue) => postList);
}
```

- Else, if you want your mockdata to be json and convert it into `List<Post>`,
  save your mock .json file in assets/mock folder
- then, add factory constructor to Post class

```
class Post {
  final int index;
  final String headingText;
  final String bodyText;

  Post({
    this.index,
    this.headingText,
    this.bodyText,
  });

  factory Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    final index = data['index'] as int;
    final headingText = data['headingText'] as String;
    final bodyText = data['bodyText'] as String;
    return Post(index: index, headingText: headingText, bodyText: bodyText);
  }
}
```

then load your json file->convert it -> return it

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

Future<List<Post>> _getPosts() async {
    String response = await rootBundle.loadString('mock/your_file_name.json');
    Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson = json.decode(response);

    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));

    final postList = Post.fromJson(parsedJson);

    return postList;
  }
```